# Android Navigation-Architecture Toolbar button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, buttonclick

I create navigation drawer activity using navigation Architecture. I put an icon on toolbar and I want to when click on the button, the new fragment should be open. 
I got this **error:**

```
android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler addShareFragment in class com.example.myapplication.MainActivity
```

Firstly, I created a `menu.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/shopping"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        android:title="shopping"
        android:onClick="addShareFragment"/>
</menu>
```

So now I can see the icon on my toolbar:

[image]

I wrote this function to my main activity.:

```
fun addFragmentA(v: View) {
        var addShareFragment= ShareFragment() // -> Önce nesne tanımlıyoruz.
        var transaction = manager.beginTransaction()//-> fragment işlemi başlatıyoruz.
        transaction.add(R.id.container, addShareFragment, "FragA") //->
        transaction.commit()
    }
```

Comment: `addShareFragment` is not `addFragmentA`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined:

```
 <item
    android:onClick="addShareFragment"
    .../>
```

You have to define in your Activity:

```
fun addShareFragment(menuItem: MenuItem){
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: Hello, i did this but i got same error.         java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080051 (com.example.myapplication:id/container) for fragment ShareFragment{2deef87 (69b77ac4-dec4-4af4-9031-d3e3d224bbd5) id=0x7f080051 FragA}

Comment: @akiilhan it isn't the same error, it s completely different. You are looking for a view that isn't in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add this item directly in your toolbar tag with an ImageButton in the activity xml file. It'll be easier for you to manage click events and have full control.

For that you have to set a theme that has no action bar like this : Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

```
            `<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/mainActivityToolbar"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

                 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>`
```

Then in your activity you get your image button ID and call your function in onClickListener.

Last thing, as you're using navigation component, you should set your action bar with navcontroller so that your hamburger icon on the left appears and works properly.

You can follow this link https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui for how to do this.

Good luck!!!